# Unity3d throwing warnings as errors at random VS2015 community

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, antivirus, suppress-warnings

Since switching to a new computer with VS2015 (from VS2013), Unity3d sometimes suddenly throws harmless warnings (cs0219 & cs0414, i.e. an assigned variable or field that is never used) as errors that block me from compiling. Besides actually "fixing" these warnings there's this dissatisfactory workaround: close unity3d and vs2015 and reopen them again.

I've read about someone running into this issues because of a virus scanner, is that possible (am using a different one than on old computer (McAffee instead of Avira)?

The VS project's setting have "treat warnings as errors" set to None, so I don't understand why this happens. The seemingly random frequency of when this happens looks suspiciously like an "outside" cause. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had what seemed to be several warnings appearing as errors!
When I scrolled down through the warnings, I noticed there truly was an error listed at the very end.

ERROR...
"Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Trying to emit a local from a different ILGenerator"

CAUSE...
The error occurred because I had just put a TRY CATCH statement inside a COROUTINE.  Unity doesn't like that!

SOLUTION...
I resolved the error be removing all Try Catch statements from all Coroutines.